# Best way to sanitize some data for importing into postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns with `date` in the YYMMDD format and a `time` in the HHMMSS format, they are strings like `150103    132244`. These are close to a quarter of a billion records. What would be the best way to sanitize the data prior to importing to PostgreSQL? Is there a way to do this while importing, for instance?

Comment: It depends what else you need to do with the data, I guess. If it's otherwise in a suitable CSV format, I'd probably use `COPY FROM` into `text` columns and then re-format the fields once in the DB. But there's any number of scripting languages that could prepare the file first if you preferred.

Comment: @IMSoP: Yes, this is a raw csv file. Sorry, do you mean pre-process before importing with, say Python? Or you mean doing something after importing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data can be converted to timestamp with time zone using the function [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
with example(d, t) as (
    values ('150103', '132244')
)

select d, t, to_timestamp(concat(d, t), 'yymmddhh24miss')
from example;

   d    |   t    |      to_timestamp      
--------+--------+------------------------
 150103 | 132244 | 2015-01-03 13:22:44+01
(1 row)
```

You can import a file into a table with *temporary* columns (d, t):

```
create table example(d text, t text);
copy example from ....
```

add a timestamp with time zone column, convert the data and drop redundant text columns:

```
alter table example add tstamp_column timestamptz;

update example
set tstamp_column = to_timestamp(concat(d, t), 'yymmddhh24miss');

alter table example drop d, drop t;
```